# Best practices to implement dotnet core web api with the option to use horizontal scaling in cloud

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core, autoscaling

We have created a dotnet core web api project which is using SQL Server database. Now, we are planning to deploy this project to Microsoft Azure.

While the deployment of this application, we are also considering to enable autoscaling option (horizontal scaling).

Before, we do it. We want to have some questions that we want to clarify.

Should we need to add some additional code in our application which allows autoscaling to work properly?

Properly in a sense, as there can be more than one instance of the application running because of horizontal scaling. We are using database and more than one instance is running will it case race condition (i.e., two resources accessing the same data at a time). I mean we can add a transaction (or use locking) in our code to avoid these kinds of scenarios?

I want to know that is there any best practices to follow while implementing that kind of application?

Thank you and waiting for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following points when designing an autoscaling strategy:

- The system must be designed to be horizontally scalable. Avoid making
  assumptions about instance affinity; do not design solutions that
  require that the code is always running in a specific instance of a
  process. When scaling a cloud service or web site horizontally, do
  not assume that a series of requests from the same source will always
  be routed to the same instance. For the same reason, design services
  to be stateless to avoid requiring a series of requests from an
  application to always be routed to the same instance of a service.
  When designing a service that reads messages from a queue and
  processes them, do not make any assumptions about which instance of
  the service handles a specific message because autoscaling could
  start additional instances of a service as the queue length grows.
  The [Competing Consumers pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/dn568101(v=pandp.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) describes how to handle this
  scenario.
- If the solution implements a long-running task, design this task to
  support both scaling out and scaling in. Without due care, such a
  task could prevent an instance of a process from being shutdown
  cleanly when the system scales in, or it could lose data if the
  process is forcibly terminated. Ideally, refactor a long-running task
  and break up the processing that it performs into smaller, discrete
  chunks. The [Pipes and Filters pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/dn568100(v=pandp.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) provides an example of how you
  can achieve this. Alternatively, you can implement a checkpoint
  mechanism that records state information about the task at regular
  intervals, and save this state in durable storage that can be
  accessed by any instance of the process running the task. In this
  way, if the process is shutdown, the work that it was performing can
  be resumed from the last checkpoint by using another instance.

For more information, follow the doc : **https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/best-practices-auto-scaling.md**

Answer (score 1):

Regarding this:

> Properly in a sense, as there can be more than one instance of the application running because of horizontal scaling. We are using database and more than one instance is running will it case race condition (i.e., two resources accessing the same data at a time). I mean we can add a transaction (or use locking) in our code to avoid these kinds of scenarios?

Please keep in mind that, even if the app is running on a single machine, requests will still be handled concurrently. This means that even on a single machine 2 requests can cause the same entry in the database to be updated. So the above questions about race conditions apply to single instance web apps as well.

Try to avoid locking: the whole point of (horizontal) scaling is to gain performance benefits. By using locks you effectively remove this benefits as only one process at a time can use the locked resource.

Other points of considerations are:

- If you are using an in-memory cache you might want to swap it out for a [distributed cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-3.0).
- The guidance at [the MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/design-principles/scale-out)